# SQL Server stored procedure intermediate tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

In SQL Server 2005, I have a query that involves a bunch of large-ish joins (each table is on the order of a few thousand rows to a few million rows, and the tables average probably the equivalent of 10-15 columns of integers and datetimes.

To make the query faster, I am thinking about splitting up the one big query into a stored procedure that does a couple of the joins, stores that result in some temporary table, and then joins that temporary table with another temporary table that was also the result of a few joins.

I am currently using table variables to store the intermediate tables, and the performance one off is noticeably better. But in production, `tempdb` seems to be having an IO bottleneck.

Is there a better way to think about solving such a problem? I mean, is using table variables way off base here?

Comment: Can you give us more details on the query? I wouldn't think that splitting a single, set-based query into multiple temp-tables and queries would make it faster....

Comment: How does your execution plan look?

Comment: there are about 8 joins involved. Execution plan is enormous with all kinds of merging, and seeking and scanning various tables

Comment: can you post the information from the table scans?  I assume those are the costliest?

Comment: If you're using a bunch of joins that are forcing table scans, you might find that an extra index or two can help the performance. It sounds like you've already checked the execution plan for the query - did it suggest that any indexes were missing? You can also run one of my favorite **[quick missing index checks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135978.aspx#S4)** or check out some **[general info about finding missing indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345417.aspx)**.

Comment: This will be very hard to answer without a sample of the query and a description of the table keys (which is why I am commenting and not answering).  There are lots of things you can do in queries that make them not use indexes.  You are not off-base with this approach, I have seen it work well.  But I have also seen it perform worse than a large join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table Variables can take up [quite a lot of memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/03/30/sql-server-table-variable-vs-local-temporary-table.aspx) in TempDB.

In large production environments, I have seen better SQL coders than I utilize standard tables for this purpose; They are essentially temp tables, but they create them as regular tables and give them a special prefix or suffix. This has the added benefit (as with temp tables) of being able to utilize indexes to help with execution.

If you can use a standard table or utilize a temp table that is accessed by all steps of your complex execution, you may be able to resolve your memory problem.

Think of it as a place to cache data. In fact, you can update this "cache" each time your main stored procedure runs, just make sure to utilize appropriate transactions and locking.

Imagine the alternative -- If you use an enormous table variable in a stored procedure, and the stored procedure is executed 10 or 20 times simultaneously... that table variable may no longer be living just in memory.